# SUMAR TIEMPO EN SQL

Tags: sql

¿Como puedo hacer un sum de mis campos time?

tengo
op= '2:55:00'
op2 = '1:05:00'

Busco que el resultado sea total = '04:00:00'

```
    declare
@op  time,
@op2 time
set @op = '2:55:00'
set @op2 = '1:05:00'
 
select (sum((DATEPART(hh, CONVERT(time, @op))*60 + DATEPART(mi, CONVERT(time, @op)))*60+ DATEPART(SS, CONVERT(time, @op)))/60/60) +
(sum((DATEPART(hh, CONVERT(time, @op2))*60 + DATEPART(mi, CONVERT(time, @op2)))*60+ DATEPART(SS, CONVERT(time, @op2)))/60/60
) as horas
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! sql generico para cualquier base de datos???

Answer (score 1):

No se pueden sumar tiempos de esa forma porque el tiempo está diseñado para indicar un momento del día. Nunca se pregunta: ¿Cuanto es las 7am más las 2pm? Lo que se pregunta es ¿Qué hora será cuando pase una hora y cinco minutos después de las 2:55am?

Lo que un humano normal hace es sumar el tiempo por partes. Lo cual quedaría similar a esto.

```
DECLARE @op  time,
        @op2 time;

SET @op  = '2:55:00';
SET @op2 = '1:05:00';

SELECT DATEADD( HH, DATEPART(HH, @op2), DATEADD( MI, DATEPART(MI, @op2),  DATEADD( SS, DATEPART(SS, @op2), @op))) AS horas;
```

Sin embargo, resulta más eficiente convertir el segundo valor a la unidad más pequeña y solo hacer una suma. Para hacer eso, obtenemos la diferencia del segundo valor con respecto a la hora cero. Así podemos simplificar la operación.

```
DECLARE @op  time,
        @op2 time;

SET @op  = '2:55:00';
SET @op2 = '1:05:00';

SELECT DATEADD( SS, DATEDIFF( SS, '00:00', @op2), @op) AS horas;
```

Comment: Buen dia, gracias, no busco sumar "horas del dia", sino unos contadores, como el tiempo de operacion de una maquina o sensor

Comment: Precisamente hacia allá va mi comentario. El tipo de dato time es para guardar "horas del día" no contadores. Para eso es mejor un entero con segundos o milisegundos dependiendo de la precisión que se busque.